# What is the status of logically pointless adjectives and adverbs, such as chairy or chairly?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, neologisms, derivational-morphology, derivation

Adjectives and adverbs can be formed by adding "y" or "ly" to e.g. a noun, such as:

```
heart -> hearty, heartily
```

However, sometimes these words are not in use, or make no logical sense, such as:

```
chair -> chairy, chairly
```

Although you could come up with a situation where you'd use "chairy", e.g. "this block of wood looks quite chairy", you'd probably be more likely to use "chairish" or "chair-like". And if you read all the books in the world, you'd probably never come across the word "chairly" or "chairily".

**What is the status of words like these?** Do they exist because they are technically correct and their meaning is obvious? Do they not exist until someone (notable) uses them in a (notable) text?

Or, to make the question more specific: if I were to create a spell checker, should I allow or disallow these words?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I added a more specific question.

Comment: When forming adverbs, it's only usual to add "-ly" to an adjective, not to a noun. "Heartily" is from "hearty" and not directly from "heart". If you're using "heart, hearty, heartily" as an analogy, the parallel triplet starting with "chair" would be "chair, chairy, chair**i**ly".

Comment: Validly-formed derivatives that aren't actually used (but might in principle be understood in appropriate contexts) are just ***non-idiomatic***. That's regardless of whether they're considered "valid words" or just "ad-hoc nonce-terms". Whether or not you should configure your spellchecker to accept them is a personal stylistic choice (assuming the spell-checker allows this, and you know how to do it). Issues concerning stylistic choices are inherently Off Topic here

Comment: 'Adjectives and adverbs can be formed by adding "y" or "ly" to e.g. a noun, such as _aardvark / radiator / oesophagus_ ...'.  This is claiming absolute productivity* for what is merely a rule-of-thumb – the 'rule' certainly doesn't guarantee lexicalisation. If one is unsure, one needs to check for wordness in a dictionary with a good pedigree (preferably OED) (some would argue that inclusion in the more comprehensive (wrt number of headwords) Wiktionary is quite reasonable endorsement). //* The alternative reading is 'it works for nouns such as 'heart', ie for those with which it works'.)

Comment: The question ' should I allow or disallow these words?' is loaded. I'd argue that the space-bounded strings not found even in Wiktionary are until proven otherwise non-words, candidate words. A word is recognised, used and understood by a reasonable number of native speakers. Still a loose definition, but better than 'any space-bounded string one likes to commit to paper'.

Answer (score 4):

Whether or not you should set your spell checker to allow those words is largely a matter of how adventurous you'd like to be in your writing - how willing you are to make your reader second guess what it is you're getting at, whether you have a passable command of the English language.

As far as their status goes, though there's no universally accepted terminology for these, here's one approach from the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1623.

> To a very large extent speakers know words as individual items of
> vocabulary. We know, for example, that the word for the area over
> which a bishop has charge is *bishopric*, not ∗*bishopdom* – and
> conversely that the word denoting the area over which a king rules is
> *kingdom*, not ∗*kingric*; that there are words *unfaithfulness* and *infidelity*, but not ∗*infaithfulity* or ∗*unfidelness*; and so on. Words like *bishopric*, *kingdom*, *unfaithfulness*, *infidelity* we
> will refer to as **established** words: they are recognised as part of
> the vocabulary of the language.
>
> Established words are individually familiar to speakers of the
> language and can be found in standard dictionaries [...] In speaking or
> writing we do not always restrict ourselves to established words: we
> can create new words or use words we have heard before but which have
> not yet become established.
>
> Creating new words is in general subject to rules or constraints. For
> example, the rules of Present-day English word-formation allow
> *policeability* as a word, but not ∗*priestric* or ∗*pick-basket*. People vary in their subjective reaction to new words, and some will
> find *policeability* inelegant or otherwise open to criticism, but it
> nevertheless differs very clearly in its linguistic status from
> ∗*priestric* and ∗*pick-basket*. *Policeability* is formed from the
> established verb *police* by adding the adjective-forming suffix
> ·*able*, and then adding a further suffix, with modification of
> ·*able*, to yield a noun that might be used in such a sentence as *The
> Commissioner questioned the policeability of the new regulations*.
> But ∗*priestric* and ∗*pick-basket* do not conform to the present-day
> rules; ∗*priestric* is analogous to *bishopric* but ·*ric* is no
> longer available as an element for forming new words, and the pattern
> seen in *pickpocket* (plain form of the verb + noun in a direct object
> relation) is likewise no longer available for forming new words so
> ∗*pick-basket* is not admissible.
>
> Words which conform to the rules of word-formation we will call
> **grammatical**, extending this term from syntax to morphology. Similarly, words that do not conform to these rules and which are not
> established we call **ungrammatical** and mark with the familiar
> asterisk notation. Grammatical words like *policeability* which are
> not established will be referred to as **potential words**: they have
> the potential to become established. Words which have been used but
> have not become established are commonly called ‘nonce-words’; as we
> have defined ‘potential’ word as a grammatical word that is not
> established the category will cover nonce-words as well as words that
> have not in fact been used.

Comment: Thank you. That is a very interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Your spell checker should disallow the words, but include a feature to allow new words to be added.

Comment: +1.  It is useful for a spell-checker to warn the writer about probable misprints like "chairy".

Comment: @curiouserandcuriouser -- There are roughly a million English words.  There is no chance that a list of the words could be collected without some errors.  It would be foolish to create a tool that embeds the list without some facilities for correcting errors.

Comment: Well of course, but we're not talking about allowing words that have been left out in error, we're talking about words that exist theoretically but make no sense or are not in general use.

Comment: This doesn't answer the main question, and reads more like very general advice on spelling checkers.